# Riemann integrable implies Stieltjes integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f:[a, b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bounded and Riemann integrable.  If $\alpha$ is a BV integrator that is, say, also, continuous, then is $f$ Riemann integrable ($\alpha$)?  What if $f$ is assumed to have a countable set of discontinuity points?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is absolutely continuous, then it is true, because $f$ is equal a.e. [$\mu_{\alpha}$] to a continuous function. However, if $\alpha$ is, say, the Cantor function, then there might be a problem.